# Problems in updating mavenized Grails 2.4.4 to 2.5.6

Tags: grails, maven-3

Updated the pom.xml with new dependencies etc. After trying to run "mvn clean install" I get an error: [groovyc] ResourceLoader must not be null. Couldn't find anything about this in google etc. Anyone been having same problems? Maven version is 3.2.3 and Java version is 1.7.0_17.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue seemed to be latest MongoDB plugin 6.1.2. Using 6.0.0 solved the issue. And now some other issues remaini